# How to change my below Pgsql Query

Tags: postgresql

I would like to execute the below query by passing some values from applet side tables.

My table is

```
style_no       | version_no | style_id
---------------------+------------+----
 Menshirt      |     1      |      861
 Menshirt      |     2      |      870
 Tops          |     1      |      893
 Childwear     |     1      |      856
 Childwear     |     2      |      978
```

If user select MenShirt with version 1,Tops with version 1,ChildWear with version 2 details, so my StylenoStr arguments = (MenShirt, Tops, Childwear) and VernoStr argument = (1, 1, 2). My problem is the below query retrieves the data with MenShirt details for Version 2 which is no needed here. How do I write a query to get results for only selected data? I am using Pgsql.

Actual query:

```
select style_id, style_no, version_no 
from style 
where style_no in (" + StylenoStr + ") 
  and version_no in (" + VernoStr + ")
```

Executed query:

```
select style_id, style_no, version_no 
from style 
where style_no in ('Menshirt', 'Tops', 'Childwear') 
  and version_no in ('1', '1', '2');
```

Result I am getting:

```
style_id | style_no        | version_no
---------+-----------------+------------
     861 | Menshirt        |     1
     870 | Menshirt        |     2
     893 | Tops            |     1
     978 | Childwear       |     2
```

Result I need is:

```
 style_id | style_no       | version_no
----------+----------------+------------
      861 | Menshirt       |     1
      893 | Tops           |     1
      978 | Childwear      |     2
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's impossible to read the query. SQL is code, so treat it as such (indentation, uppercase for keywords, etc..). With proper formatting, you will get people to help you more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select style_id, style_no, version_no
from style
where (style_no, version_no) in (('Menshirt', '1'),
                                 ('Tops', '1'),
                                 ('Childwear', '2'));
```